# PostgreSQL: Usage of text parameter in nested CASE WHEN significantly slows down the query

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, database-performance

Using PostgreSQL 11.1, I have a function with a parameter of type `text`. It is heavily used in `CASE WHEN` structures, often nested.

Recently, I came across a very strange phenomenon:
Let's say in my function I have something like `CASE WHEN $1 = 'foo') THEN id ...`, I now execute the function with parameter value `foo`. Everything works as expected, but very slow.

If, inside the function, I replace `$1 = 'foo'` with `'foo' = 'foo'` it should have the same effect as passing the value `foo` for `$1`. And indeed the result is the same. It is just way faster!

In my real-world example, the difference is 400 milliseconds to 25 seconds!

I have created two functions (see below) which resemble the phenomenon. The code there is highly repetitive to gain some significance.
On my machine, the version without parameter takes 6 seconds, while the one with parameter takes about 16 seconds. (I have wrapped the execution in a PLV8 `DO` statement so that the result won't bloat the client)

So, my questions are: How come? Why does comparing a parameter value with a string take significantly more time than comparing two strings? I cannot understand that.
Second question: Can I do something here to improve the performance? I need that parameter.

**Edit: results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

Prepending `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to the function calls gives me these results:

without parameter

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=5429.874..5432.217 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.615 ms
Execution Time: 5435.469 ms
```

with parameter

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=15585.637..15588.569 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.213 ms
Execution Time: 15591.640 ms
```

**Edit 2: results of auto-log**

without parameter

```
Aggregate  (cost=47.52..47.53 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6248.177..6248.178 rows=1 loops=1)
          CTE myData
            ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.003..689.085 rows=10000000 loops=1)
                  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
          CTE nestedCases
            ->  CTE Scan on "myData"  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.004..2692.660 rows=10000000 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on "nestedCases"  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.005..5434.799 rows=10000000 loops=1)
```

with parameter

```
Aggregate  (cost=197.52..197.53 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=16568.033..16568.033 rows=1 loops=1)
          CTE myData
            ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.002..728.866 rows=10000000 loops=1)
                  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
          CTE nestedCases
            ->  CTE Scan on "myData"  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.010..12851.991 rows=10000000 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on "nestedCases"  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.012..15686.157 rows=10000000 loops=1)
```

**Appendix: Full code of functions**

The code is basically nonsense: It generates a huge series and fetches the value 10 times with a nested `CASE WHEN`.

A) Function with parameter

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_with_param(role text)
 RETURNS integer[]
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
 WITH "myData" AS (
   SELECT generate_series(1,10000000) AS id
),

"nestedCases" AS (
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
      CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
           WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id2,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id3,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id4,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id5,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id6,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
      CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
           WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id7,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id8,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id9,

 CASE WHEN ($1 = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN ($1 = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN ($1 = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id10

FROM "myData"
)
SELECT array_agg(id) FROM "nestedCases"
$function$
```

B) Function with**out** parameter. I have replaced `$1` with `/*P*/'foo'/*P*/` just so that you can see what I did here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_without_param()
 RETURNS integer[]
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
 WITH "myData" AS (
   SELECT generate_series(1,10000000) AS id
),
"nestedCases" AS (
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
      CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
           WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id2,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id3,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id4,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id5,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id6,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
      CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
           WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id7,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id8,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id9,

 CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'bar') THEN 0
 WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN 
       CASE WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'huhu') AND id = 1 THEN id + 452
            WHEN (/*P*/'foo'/*P*/ = 'foo') THEN id
       END   
 END  
 AS id10

FROM "myData"
)
SELECT array_agg(id) FROM "nestedCases"
$function$
```

Comment: there is something strange in your example. How $1 can be 'foo' and 'huhu' in the same time?

Comment: Get execution plans for both cases, then you will see. `auto_explain` can perhaps help.

Comment: @Radim Bača As I said, the code is not intended to make much sense, it should just show the phenomenon.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I've added the results above but in my opinion, they are not really exciting.

Comment: Oh, that's because the interesting stuff happens inside a function. Use `auto_explain` with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on`.

Comment: BTW: `role` is a bad name for a parameter. Second: the second example's conditions all degrade to constants. And the result cannot be NULL. In the first example the resulting expression can be NULL, since there is no default expression for the case.

Comment: @joop Thaks for those hints. Yes, `role` is a bad name, but should not cause the trouble here, since it is not reserved in Postgres according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-keywords-appendix.html Second: The expressions could be NULL yes, but I don't see the point. I'm just comparing executing the function with a parameter value for which the expression is not null, i.e. `foo`. If I change the parameter definition to `"myAwesomeParameter" text default 'foo'`, the result is exactly the same: 16 seconds

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thanks for that hint! I've added the auto_log results. Maybe you can find out something out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a hard coded constant, all the expressions can be evaluated a plan time. Since query plans are cached in PL/pgSQL functions, that happens only once.

If you use a parameter, the expressions have to be evaluated at run time each time the function is called.